# Is it good design to have Skeletal Classes/ Abstract classes without actually implementing any methods?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I am designing an interface, for which I plan to to have an abstract class or skeletal class as per **Effective Java**(Joshua Bloch) *Item 18: Prefer interfaces to abstract classes*.
The reason is to guard future evolution of the interface from breaking the implementing classes.

As of today, I do not have any methods for which I want to provide a default implementation. Is this design okay?

Eg:

```
public interface Foo{
  public List<Baz> getBazList();
  public String getId();
  public String getName();
}

public abstract class AbstractFoo implements Foo{
}
```

Comment: I would not have an abstract class without methods.  It adds nothing.  It's contrary to the Bloch recommendation.  The interface is enough.

Comment: No. Abstract classes should provide *common behavior* for all its children. If there is nothing to share with the children there should be no such super class.

Comment: For someone who downvoted this question, Can you tell why that downvote?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple but powerful test you can apply in this and similar cases.

Ask yourself this question: "How would I use this abstract class in my code? What do I plan to do with it that I can't with my interface?"

If the answer is "nothing", then get rid of it. If a construct serves no real purpose, it just adds clutter to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the interface might be expanded in the future, thus rendering the child classes incompatible (since they do not implement those methods), using that empty abstract superclass might be a way to keep it able to compile easily.

I.e. today you have

```
public interface Foo{
  public List<Baz> getBazList();
  public String getId();
  public String getName();
}

public abstract class AbstractFoo implements Foo{
}

public class Foo1 extends AbstractFoo {
  public List<Baz> getBazList() { ... }
  public String getId()  { ... }
  public String getName()  { ... }
}

public class Foo2 extends AbstractFoo {
  public List<Baz> getBazList() { ... }
  public String getId()  { ... }
  public String getName()  { ... }
}
```

In the future, someone changes the interface (for whatever reason), so you do the following:

```
// extended
public interface Foo{
  public List<Baz> getBazList();
  public String getId();
  public String getName();
  public void breakMyCode();
}

// provide dummy implementation for breakMyCode()
public abstract class AbstractFoo implements Foo{
  public void breakMyCode() {
     throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
  }
}

// unchanged
public class Foo1 extends AbstractFoo {
  public List<Baz> getBazList() { ... }
  public String getId()  { ... }
  public String getName()  { ... }
}

// unchanged
public class Foo2 extends AbstractFoo {
  public List<Baz> getBazList() { ... }
  public String getId()  { ... }
  public String getName()  { ... }
}
```

Is this a good idea? Not really. When the interface gets extended, there is probably a reason for it, and just providing a dummy implementation that either does nothing or throws a RuntimeException doesn't make the program work as expected. It's rather a way to hide ommissions during compile but let them break the program during runtime.

Comment: And you only really have to think about this if you're writing pre-Java 8 code, starting from 8 you can add default method implementations in the interfaces themselves.